# How to find sum using reduce, pipe and combinelatest?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

Values is list of obervables over input fields

```
    var example = combineLatest(values);
```

How do I find sum of values in text field.

```
    example.subscribe(val => {
        console.log('Sum:', val);
    });
```

Having subscriber over it gives me output of the form

*Sum: (2) ["1", "2"]*

Piping over combineLatest gives me NaN

```
     .pipe(reduce((acc, one) => {
         var a =Number(acc) + Number(one);
         console.log(a);
         return a;
     }, 0));
```

Comment: The logs are all `NaN`?

Comment: yes I have shown logs above .

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question reduce only emits if your Observable completes. To be able to analyse your issue we need to know what exactly your Observable (values) is and when those are set and how you complete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to reduce the Observable, you have to reduce the array it emits.

```
var example = combineLatest(values).pipe(
  map(array => array.reduce((pv, cv) => pv + Number(cv), 0))
);
```